# Intent passed into onHandleIntent is missing intent extras that I set

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-pendingintent, extras

I am creating an Intent and adding a string extra to it, then I create a PendingIntent, which is given to the alarm manager to execute:

```
String value = "someValue";

Intent intent = new Intent(this, FetchService.class);
intent.putExtra(AppConstants.KEY, value);

alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Up until this point, everything is fine, and I checked with a debugger that the extra was actually set. Next, when the onHandleIntent(intent) is called inside my service, the extra doesn't seem to exist anymore

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // App crashes here
    String value = intent.getStringExtra(AppConstants.KEY);

    ...
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why the extra is not there. Have I missed something?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you replace the last argument of `getService` with one of the FLAG constants defined in PendingIntent (e.g. `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was missing the PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT when creating my PendingIntent as Karakuri pointed out.